# write to clipboard without dependencies

Tags: linux, clipboard

is there a way to write to Linux clipboard (with bash) without having extra dependencies?
Writing it to the selection buffer would be enough.
I'm on a system where I can't install anything.
Why can I access devices like regular files, but the clipboard is so inaccessible?

Comment: Just redirect your bash output to a file and reference that instead of the clipboard.

Comment: Unforunally i need to insert the output to a program with no ability to read the file.